# asp.net mvc check checkboxes from serialized modelstate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I'm building a form wizard. So far its working, I do it by serializing the object into a hidden field. 
In step 2 of the wizard, **I'm generating checkboxes based on a list from my database**.

My view looks like this.

```
@{
List<MvcApplication2.Models.DB.t_previous_exp> prevExpt = ViewBag.prevexp;
}

@foreach (var checkbox1 in prevExpt)
{    
   input type="checkbox" name="Step2.PrevExp" value="checkbox.ID" />checkbox.name 
}
```

They all get added to the model with their ID as value. But when moving to for instance step one in the wizard(all that data is saved, and it shows up) and **BACK** to step2 no checkboxes are checked.

I understand I need to somehow check the value from the modelstate and loop over it. 
But I can't understand how... They model values are stored in a string[], and I understand I'm looping over databasevalues.
Can I somehow use checkboxfor?

Comment: have you tried to add the attribute checked="checked" to the input based on your model?

Comment: there's the rub, value of true is not checked

Comment: Hi! How would I implent that? Should I create a viewmodel or could i use checkboxfor to achive this?

Comment: @CarlPalsson, I posted an answer that hasn't been tested, I more wanted to give you the idea of setting a razor variable against the true/false value that checkboxes return and populating checked status